# How to disable horizontal scroll bar in FlowLayoutPanel?

Tags: c#, winforms, scrollbar, flowlayoutpanel

I have a FlowLayoutPanel and there are multiple controls on it. I only want to scroll in vertical direction. But when I set `AutoScroll = true`, I got both Vertical and Horizontal Scroll bars. How could I disable the horizontal scroll bar and only keep the vertical scroll bar working?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

- Set **AutoScroll** to true
- Set **WrapContents** to false.
- Make sure the size is wider than the
  controls' width plus the width of a vertical scrollbar.

The horizontal scrollbar should disappear.  If it doesn't, please provide some more information.

Comment: Thanks for this! Just now I play with it and I find if I set flowDirection=leftToRight, flowlayoutPanel.HorizontalScroll.Visible = false, wrapContents = true. It works...So there is multiple way to do this? Thank you anyway! :)

Comment: I have noticed that enabling WrapContents (with LeftToRight flow) will create "line feeds" and thus never needing any horizontal scroll bar. actually I dont like that, I want a WrapContents to false, but I still want FlowBreak property to work, to control manually the line feeds. However this doesn't work. FlowBreak property is ignored, by a sheer bug of that control, if WrapContents is false. booh microsoft. yet again.

Comment: I am using WrapContents. To achieve the result I want, I have enclosed my FlowLayoutPanel in a Panel control, then I set the Panel's AutoScroll to true, the FlowLayoutPanel's autoscroll to false, and it works!

Answer (score 5):

**Set AutoScroll to true.
Set WrapContents to false.
Set Padding Right to 10.**

It's work pretty fine for me.

Comment: I thought "no way, it can't work", but yeah, the padding right made trick :S

Comment: This trick worked. 
Only thing is, based on child control's font size you will have to adjust padding.

Comment: how about disabling the verticalscrollbar instead of the horizontalscrollbar needed? @user2559770 ?

Answer (score -1):

Here is how I implement to have multiple labels on a FlowLayoutPanel with wrap text(WrapContents = true), verticalscrollbar only.

1. I have a flowLayoutPanel1 on a form
2. Set properties of form and flowLayoutPanel1 like below:

**form:**

```
AutoScroll = True
FormBorderStyle = Sizable(default)
```

**flowLayoutPanel1:**

```
Anchor = Top, Left, Right
AutoSize = True
FlowDirection = TopDown
WrapContents = true
```

3. Implement this code on form class for testing

```html
int coorY = 0;
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(new Label 
                { 
                    Location = new Point(0, coorY + 20),
                    Font = new Font("Segoe UI", 10f),
                    Text = "I have a FlowLayoutPanel and there are multiple controls on it. I only want to scroll in vertical",
                    Width = flowLayoutPanel1.Width,
                    AutoSize = true
                });
                coorY += 20;
            }
        }
```

[Vertical scrollbar in action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7EX4.png)