# Hide FlowLayoutPanel's Horizontal Scrollbar

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a FlowLayoutPanel in which i add some controls, Here are my properties

```
FlowLayoutPanel.AutoScroll = true;
FlowLayoutPanel.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.TopDown;
FlowLayoutPanel.WrapContents = false;
```

Now i want only the vertical scrollbar to be visible regardless of the size of the controls being added to the panel so i tried many solutions present here at stackoverflow with no luck also i tried

```
FlowLayoutPanel.HorizontalScroll.Visible = false;
```

But the Horizontal scroll bar still visible for some reason.

Solutions i have tried

[still Not able to Hide Horizontal Scrollbar of FlowLayoutPanel in WinForms Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13320985/still-not-able-to-hide-horizontal-scrollbar-of-flowlayoutpanel-in-winforms-apps)

[How to disable horizontal scroll bar in FlowLayoutPanel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556561/how-to-disable-horizontal-scroll-bar-disabled-in-flowlayoutpanel)

Comment: If the similar question's answer does not work for you "for some reason", then please explain this mysterious reason. i.e Errors, debug info, etc.

Comment: @LeeTaylor, ofc by saying some reason is that no errors or anything but just that the scroll bar still appears... Also what kind of error do you expect from trying to hide the scroll bar ?!.

Comment: We are used to a plethora of different errors, compile error, exception thrown, incorrectly rendered, etc. So help us out and describe more fully what you see and why it's different from what you expect.

Comment: You can't just say that "all the solutions presented" don't work "for some reason". If you want you could provide links to questions you've seen and whose answers you've tried, and what happened when you tried them (scroll bar still shows? anything else?) But to blanketly assure closers that **all** the other possible solutions here "don't work" is just wasted typing. Be specific or don't bother.